# VS grammar: `option` cannot be nested inside `span`

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, jquery-select2

I'm creating a custom Vue component that serves as a wrapper for applying a jQuery Select2 widget to a traditional HTML `select` element.

Everything works just fine, but Visual Studio is throwing up a grammatical warning about the way I'm implementing my solution:

```
<select2 v-on:change="change($event)">
    <option></option>
    <option v-for="(option, optionIndex) in options"
            v-bind:key="optionIndex"
            v-bind:value="option.value">{{option.text}}</option>
</select2>
```

There's a green squiggly line underneath each `option` element with the following note:

> Element 'option' cannot be nested inside 'span'.

The message is clear and understandable. `option` elements are supposed to be inside `select`, but since I'm using a custom `select2` component, Visual Studio is getting confused.

The problem I have with this is that my custom component is literally just a wrapper for a `select` element, so it technically yields the appropriate output.

Is there a way to force Visual Studio to ignore this particular case so I don't have the grammar warnings showing up in my scrollbar?

Is there another way to implement this component so it doesn't complain?

I'm thinking I might be able to add another prop for `options` and pass in an array to create the `option` nodes inside the component instead of passing them through a slot, but it gets complicated because we have a lot of components that use this with different option properties to yield the value and text (i.e. `option.label` and `option.id` instead of `option.text` and `option.value`), so it seems like the slot is what suits our needs best.

Yet another idea I had would be to create a `select2option` component that is just a wrapper for standard options, but that seems excessive and I can't imagine our other developers to intuitively use those over standard `option` elements.

Just wondering if there is anything about Visual Studio that can be done to remedy this behavior without turning off grammar completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [DOM Template Parsing Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats), you should be able to do

```
<select is="select2" v-on:change="change($event)">
    <option></option>
    <option v-for="(option, optionIndex) in options"
            v-bind:key="optionIndex"
            v-bind:value="option.value">{{option.text}}</option>
</select>
```

Also note that [proper practice is to have a hyphen in your component name](https://github.com/pablohpsilva/vuejs-component-style-guide#vue-component-names).

Comment: Thank for the documentation link. So the `is` attribute causes the `select` to render as a `select2` then, am I understanding this correctly? The reason I'm creating the component is because it is often rendered dynamically and I need it to initialize the widget whenever it gets mounted and rendered.

Comment: Yes, the `is` attribute lets you use the tag the HTML requires, but Vue will interpret it as a component.

Comment: Awesome. I think I remember seeing that before but I didn't know how it was used. Appreciate the quick responses. And thanks for the note about hyphens.